# If $N \triangleleft G$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(N)=\mathrm{Inn}(N)$, show that $G=NC_G(N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been working on this problem, without success...

Let $N \triangleleft G$ and assume that every automorphism of $N$ is inner.  Show that $G=NC_G(N)$.

Since every automorphism of $N$ is inner, we have $\mathrm{Aut}(N)=\mathrm{Inn}(N) \cong N/Z(N) \cong N/(N \cap C_G(N))$.  This led me to try to apply the Diamond Theorem in some way (if $N \triangleleft G$ and $H \le G$, then $H \cap N \triangleleft H$ and $H/(H \cap N) \cong NH/N$.), since $C_G(N) \triangleleft G$ (because $C_G(N) \triangleleft N_G(N)=G$) but I couldn't get anywhere with it.

Since $N$ and $C_G(N)$ are normal, we already know that $NC_G(N)$ is a subgroup.  So my other approach was to establish a bijection $G/N \leftrightarrow C_G(N)$ or $G/C_G(N) \leftrightarrow N$.  I was unable to find a good way to do this though.

What is wrong with these approaches?

I'd appreciate a hint on what direction to take with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have additional information about $K$? For example $K$ is complete?

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to show that $G\subseteq NC_G(N)$ so, let $g\in G$ then as $N$ is normal in $G$ we have $\phi_g(N)=gNg^{-1}=N$ and so we have $\phi_g\mid_ K\in Aut(N)=Inn(N)$. So there is an $n\in N$ such that $$\phi_g(x)=\phi_n(x)$$ for all $x$ in $N$. It seems that $n^{-1}g$ in the intersection of all $C_G(x), x\in N$ which is $C_G(N)$. This means that $g=n(n^{-1}g)\in NC_G(N)$.

This is my attempt.

Comment: I realize this is very late - know sure why I didn't reply before, sorry about that.  I see that N needs to be complete in order for this to be true, but how do we see that N is complete?  Or must this be a missing assumption?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For each $g \in G$, you wish to find $n_0 \in N$ such that $n_0^{-1}g \in C_G(N)$. That is, we want $(n_0^{-1}g)n = n(n_0^{-1}g)$ for all $n \in N$. Equivalently, we want to choose our $n_0 \in N$ so that $gng^{-1} = n_0nn_0^{-1}$ for all $n \in N$. That is, the automorphism of $N$ we get from conjugation by $g$ should be an inner automorphism of $N$. This is the case since $\operatorname{Aut}(N) = \operatorname{Inn}(N)$.